# Rework EventWaitHandle to asynchronously await signal

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I need to change current code to not block current thread when EventWaitHandle.WaitOne is called. Problem is that I am awaiting system-wide event. I did not find any proper replacement yet.

Code:

```
EventWaitHandle handle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "Local event", out screenLoadedSignalMutexWasCreated);

        StartOtherApp();

        if (screenLoadedSignalMutexWasCreated)
        {
            isOtherAppFullyLoaded = handle.WaitOne(45000, true);

            if (isOtherAppFullyLoaded )
            {
                // do stuff
            }
            else
            {
                // do stuff
            }

            handle.Dispose();
            signalingCompleted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isOtherAppFullyLoaded = false;
            throw new Exception(" ");
        }
```

I need app to continue and not stop on the line where I call WaitOne, ideally there would be await. How can I implement this ?

Comment: So why are you calling WaitOne in the first place if you do not wish to wait? I do not understand what you want to happen.

Comment: I deleted my answer as you need a system-wide implementation which i overlooked

Comment: What behavior are you looking for? Do you want your application to continue executing, and be notified when the other application is fully loaded (or when the 45 seconds elapses)?

Comment: Check out [ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02x3daw5(v=vs.110).aspx), which has a working example. The `waitObject` you pass can be a system-wide object (a global `EventWaitHandle`, for example).

Comment: Whis was original code which I need to rewrite. It was good when we had it at the end of app1, but we moved that code to launch sooner because second app takes too long to load. Then the blockage from wait handle is a problem

Comment: Yes I believe I have made a successful try with RegisterWaitForSingleObject yesterday, I found some code in MSDN that seems to help, I am awaiting verification

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `AsyncFactory.FromWaitHandle`, in my [AsyncEx library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx):

```
isOtherAppFullyLoaded = await AsyncFactory.FromWaitHandle(handle,
    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(45000));
```

The implementation uses `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject`:

```
public static Task<bool> FromWaitHandle(WaitHandle handle, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    // Handle synchronous cases.
    var alreadySignalled = handle.WaitOne(0);
    if (alreadySignalled)
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    if (timeout == TimeSpan.Zero)
        return Task.FromResult(false);

    // Register all asynchronous cases.
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var threadPoolRegistration = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(handle,
        (state, timedOut) => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)state).TrySetResult(!timedOut),
        tcs, timeout);
    tcs.Task.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        threadPoolRegistration.Dispose();
    }, TaskScheduler.Default);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I used pretty much code as you are writing in second code block. Using additional non-.NET framework libs is discouraged in the project

Comment: If I call this method 10 times (without a timeout), will I then have consumed 10 threadpool threads that are now blocking while waiting for the signal to be set?

Comment: @LaFleur: No, the `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` is able to coalesce calls; IIRC up to 31 handles can be waited on by a single thread pool thread. Not sure what the behavior is if you use the same handle.

Comment: Are you sure this compiles? `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` doesn't return an object with a `Dispose()` method, and also requires an additional `executeOnlyOnce` argument.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: I did simplify the code when copying it into this post; see [the original code](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/0361015459938f2eb8f3c1ad1021d19ee01c93a4/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Interop.WaitHandles/Interop/WaitHandleAsyncFactory.cs) for details.